# barely had or had barely?

Tags: adverb-placement

I'd like to know whether the order of "barely" and "had" can be turned around in the following:

> John **had barely** / **barely had** arrived home when / before the phone rang.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score -3):

While I stand corrected that your example is not actually an infinitive use of the verb, your question is similar to a split infinitive, for which the preferred sequence is verb first, 'John had barely'. Although either sequence is in common usage.

Note the classic example of a split infinitive is the Star Trek 'to boldly go', which should really be 'to go boldly'.

Comment: "Had arrived" is not an infinitive, and there is no actual rule against split infinitives.